# Git local-remote conflict with a single user

Tags: git

I am the only person to work on a single file. I have local commits and a remote repo, only for backup purposes. I do not branch at all. However, pushing to my remote was once rejected and the suggested merge resulted in conflicts.

In my case, is amending a commit after it was pushed (which I am pretty sure is what I did) the only reason why this can happen? So when I try to push again later, Git fails to find the exact change sequence that will make remote identical to local, because the local reference was amended?

Thank you!

Comment: What exact commands led to what exact errors? Right now, it sounds like you tried `git pull` and it failed to merge the remote's changes, which only has to do with local commits. It is unclear if anything else you describe actually has anything to do with your current issue.

Comment: It usually helps to have some hints from concrete conflict / error messages to debug a local / remote git conflict. Could this be provided without too much effort? That would be great.

Comment: Sorry my formulation may have been unclear. @murraybo confirmed my thought though so I marked the issue solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pushed A - B - C to the Repository. Than you changed you local History to A - B - C' . This can not pushed to the repository without rewriting the history which would lead to problems for other users. Therefore it is normally forbidden.

You can force an update by

git push origin +master:master

(Assuming the remote is name origin and local and remote branch are called master)

Attention this removes/deletes commit C from the remote repository.